# Clustering algorithm that allows existing particles to keep the cluster indices while assigning indices to new particles

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I have a very specific problem on clustering that I couldn't find the solution elsewhere. Consider first a set of N particles. I use a clustering algorithm (be it minimum spanning tree, k-means scattering, DBSCAN, or others) to obtain the clusters for this set of N particles. I store their clustering indices.

Then, I allow the particles to evolve, such that at the next snapshot these N particles have different positions as compared to the previous snapshot. Beside from this, there is a set of new M particles added in this snapshot. Therefore in this new snapshot, there are N+M particles. My question is, in this new snapshot, is there any way/method to obtain clusters, such that the N particles retain the same clustering indices from the previous snapshot, while the new M particles are assigned these old clustering indices (i.e. added to the previously found clusters), or assigned new clustering indices (i.e. create new clusters)?

EDIT: An example to elaborate my point: consider in previous snapshot, I have two clusters, cluster #1 and cluster #2. In the new snapshot, I have a new particle. This particle should then be included in cluster #1, #2, or neither, which means it is a cluster by itself, i.e. cluster #3. Note that the positions of clusters #1 and #2 are not the same in old and new snapshot.

Comment: Not really sure how you want the clustering indices to be assigned to the new M particles that entered the picture. Could you elaborate the last sentence of your question? M new particles are assigned what old clustering indices?

Comment: Hi @Ananda, please see the added statement above. Thank you.